# converting buffer message to readable utf8 using node

Tags: android, node.js, utf-8, udp, sensors

### **Question:**

**how can I make my sensor data come in as proper x,y,z coordinates or something more `human readable`??**

---

---

### **Background:**

I have packets of `sensor data` (eg. Gravity, Rotation etc..) coming from my android phone
[image]

---

Ok so I've a UDP server using nodeJS.  It is open and listening for a message data.

**server.js**

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '0.0.0.0';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(message);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

---

This message is formatted as a buffer((?) what is it really called binary?). 
[image: buffer]

This is what happens when i do `console.log(message.toString("utf8"));`
[image]

Comment: Did you try `message.toString("utf8")`?

Comment: I just created an app almost identical to yours and another socket to send it messages. It works using the `toString()`. It must be something on the Java side, make sure your JSON or whatever is in utf8.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's the app :(